# Azure AD pricing

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am really confused by the terminology included in calculating the price for Azure AD, and even calculating what pricing tiers are fulfilling my needs. Since i can not find good explanation of some terms like User forest, and what does the hours for that user forest represent.

I would like to purchase Azure AD for test automation purposes for my app. Since i do not want (or better said i am not allowed) to use production AD from my client. So i would not have a lot of users, and groups inside my AD but there may be a lot of traffic for those users.

So what would be recommended pricing tiers?

Is free tier with standard pricing tier with 750 hours be enough for 5 to 10 users and taking into calculation the fact that i would probably have test automation started a few times a day? And the test scope is only going to get bigger.

Thank you! Cheers!
Nikola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Active Directory comes in four editions—[Free, Office 365 apps, Premium P1, and Premium P2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory/). I think the free edition (has a 5,00,000 Object Limit) would be enough for you if you do not need features like Identity Protection, Conditional Access, Hybrid Identities, and other premium features.

If you are looking at deploying Virtual Machines as well, [A-Series VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/series/) are good for entry-level workloads like development and test.

Comment: I would use it to manage users and groups. To be able to fetch information about users and groups via MS Graph API and to attach some webhooks so i can get change notifications on users and groups. One thing remains unclear to me. How free is that free edition? Because when i choose Free tier in Azure price calculator i get some predefined value for User forest ( 730 hours ). And the price is around 110 $. Any clarifications on what that mean?

Comment: When you select 'Free Tier' in Calculator, it also includes 'Azure Active Directory Domain Services' which is not free. Hence it shows you the price of around $109.5. 
If you just need to manage users and groups in Azure AD (Cloud only) and use Graph /Webhook, I don't think you will need ADDS services. So you can set up a free Azure Trial Subscription, and start using AAD. Even when the If your subscription expires, you lose access to all the other resources associated with the subscription. However, the Azure AD directory remains in Azure. Let me know if this helps or if you need more info.

Comment: Thank you Nishant. This pretty much wraps everything i needed to know.